# Two layers on tmap

Tags: maps, tmap

I am trying to show two variables in the same map, using tmap. Rather than having two separate maps, I want to show variables in different colors in the same map.

```
kkmap <- tm_shape(dat_map)+ 
  tm_fill("KK",
      style = "equal", 
      title = "Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu / Share of Votes %",
      palette = "Greens") +
 tm_layout(
  legend.position = c("right", "bottom"), 
frame=FALSE) +
 tm_borders(alpha = 0.5) +
 tmap_style("natural") +
 tmap_options(max.categories = 5)
rtemap <- tm_shape(dat_map)+ 
 tm_fill("RTE",
      style = "equal", 
      title = "Recep Tayip Erdoğan / Share of Votes %",
      palette = "Greens") +
 tm_layout(
   legend.position = c("right", "bottom"), 
  frame=FALSE) +
  tm_borders(alpha = 0.5) +
  tmap_style("natural") +
  tmap_options(max.categories = 5)
```